# issue with htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm working on SEO for a website and wanted to correct some "not-found" url given by Google Webmasters tools.

So I started on the .htaccess file to do so.

```
 http://www.chateau-de-beaugency.com/fr/index.php?id=12
```

should be

```
 http://www.chateau-de-beaugency.com/fr/infos-legales-12
```

and

```
 http://www.chateau-de-beaugency.com/fr/index.php?id=42
```

should be

```
 http://www.chateau-de-beaugency.com/fr/acces-presse-42
```

and

```
 http://www.chateau-de-beaugency.com/fr/index.php?id=11
```

should be

```
 http://www.chateau-de-beaugency.com/fr/nous-contacter-11
```

and

```
 http://www.chateau-de-beaugency.com/fr/index.php?id=13
```

should be

```
 http://www.chateau-de-beaugency.com/fr/plan-du-site-13
```

and

```
 http://www.chateau-de-beaugency.com/fr/fr/-6/les-services-35/index.php?id=13
```

should be

```
 http://www.chateau-de-beaugency.com/fr/plan-du-site-13
```

and

```
 http://www.chateau-de-beaugency.com/fr/fr/-6/les-services-35/index.php?id=12
```

should be

```
 http://www.chateau-de-beaugency.com/fr/infos-legales-12
```

and

```
 http://www.chateau-de-beaugency.com/fr/chateau-de-beaugency.com/fr/
```

should be

```
 http://www.chateau-de-beaugency.com/fr/
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+/fr/fr/-6/les-services-35/index.php?id=12 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+fr/index\.php?id=12\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /fr/infos-legales-12? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(fr)/index\.php?id=(42)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/acces-presse-%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(fr)/index\.php?id=(11)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/acces-presse-%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(fr)/fr/-6/les-services-35/index.php?id=13\s [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(fr)/index\.php?id=13\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/plan-du-site-13? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(fr)/chateau-de-beaugency.com/fr/\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [R=302,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^(fr)/name-([^/]+)/?$ $1/index.php?id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your tip, but unfortunately it does not work.
Take a look, I want this :
http://www.chateau-de-beaugency.com/fr/index.php?id=12
to go there :
http://www.chateau-de-beaugency.com/fr/infos-legales-12
I have this message :
"Not Found The requested URL /fr/index.php was not found on this server."
the .htaccess is on the root of my vhost.
Ad yes there is other rules, I can send the original file if you want ?

Comment: Yes it varies, actually there are 7 different urls Google webmaster tools told me were 404.
I guess they are urls indexed by bots before I corrected my rewriteRules (which are working well), so it indexed some mix of rewrited urls with old urls, due to misconfiguration of my rules at first. If I am clear.

Comment: I thought I could keep all my rules for the good URLS and just add some exceptions hard coded for the few (7) bad URLs that Google Tool has detected. Couldn't it work ?

Comment: Can't I directly add an exception for chateau-de-beaugency.com/fr/index.php?id=12 to go chateau-de-beaugency.com/fr/infos-legales-12 ?